# Error when sending a HTTPS post request using Python's requests library with a proxy

Tags: python, python-requests

I've been getting a very strange error when sending HTTPS post requests, I've found a few similar reports, but I haven't found a solution yet. If you have any suggestions, they would be greatly appreciated!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Data/Python Projects/Experement.py", line 14, in send_request
    return requests.post(URL + '/verify', proxies=proxy).json()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 88, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 456, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 559, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 327, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 488, in urlopen
    conn = self._get_conn(timeout=pool_timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 222, in _get_conn
    return conn or self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 683, in _new_conn
    return self._prepare_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 647, in _prepare_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 179, in connect
    self._tunnel()
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\httplib.py", line 759, in _tunnel
    line = response.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
TypeError: readline() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an open bug in httplib: http://bugs.python.org/issue17849. There's a short patch attached to the issue, so you could just apply that to your copy of `httplib.py`.

I had a quick look through the commit histories of `connection.py` in urllib3 and Requests' copy of urllib3, but it didn't seem like any workaround had been applied.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in here:

```
line = response.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
TypeError: readline() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

the request's function readline does not accepts arguments other than 'self'. So it's indeed a library bug.

At the end of this discussion: https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/2159, suggests that could be a missconfigured proxy who triggers the bug, also that bug was fixed on python 2.7 as you can see here: https://bugs.python.org/issue17849

**Maybe you can consider upgrade to python3, and requests library as well.**